# Tailwindcss v3 autocomplete css class names in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, ide, tailwind-css

Tailwindcss v3 comes out with built-in JIT engine, now my VSCode stop auto-completing CSS class names because unused classes not present in generated css file.

How can I make VSCode understand all Tailwindcss-v3 class names?

Comment: You can try this extension which auto-completes tailwind classes. It also comes with a preview of the values in ``rem`` and ``px``.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

**Tailwind CSS IntelliSense** extension for Visual Studio Code enhances the Tailwind development experience by providing users with advanced features such as autocomplete, syntax highlighting, and linting.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31414964)